# What does Dr. Krauss mean by a universe from "nothing."

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, universe

I have read for a couple weeks now about a universe from nothing. I understand that the gluon field supports quarks in a proton. I understand that the universe has zero total energy. I'm confused about the beginning of the universe, and terminology.

When Dr. Lawrence Krauss debated Hamza Tzortzis, Krauss told Tzortzis that "nothing" meant "NOTHING! Zip, zero, nada!" There was no universe, no quantum, and no foam. OK, nothing means no universe. No space, time, or laws. The universe was created when nothing was there before, or it wasn't there before. Then, the Lambda CDM theory asserts a quantum foam, substrate, or some such, prior to the big bang.

**Q:** Is Dr. Krauss referring to a different model than the Lambda CDM?

**A:**

Comment: *No... laws.* I’m skeptical that Dr. Krauss thinks that. (I did not downvote.)

Comment: @G.Smith No laws because there is nothing for them to apply to. There's an earliest time and anything before that is "north of the north pole".

Comment: *I understand that the gluon field supports quarks in a proton.* What do gluons have to do with the universe-from-nothing idea?

Comment: @G.Smith
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Zp32xPzbw0

Why I brought up the gluon field: I've been watching videos that talk about empty space at the macro and micro level, but even at the macro level, there are quantum fluctuations, so we are back to the micro. I heard you can destroy a quark from empty space. So, my confusion stems from a lack of the explanation I seek.

Since I was confused, A better question might be, what kind of scalar field could be created by a fluctuation resulting in a mass that weighs 1/100,000 of a gram?

Comment: I wrote to him on facebook. I asked:
Does the Lamda CDM model not allow for your definition of nothing, and a quantum foam independent of this nothing?

He responded, "I was one of early developers of Lambda CDM model.. so yes, it allows for my definition."

I asked, "...but does this not allow for a quantum foam independent of that nothing?"
Dr. Krauss said, "quantum foam right now has no meaning as we don't have a quantum theory of gravity."

Dr. Krauss refers to a universe from nothing referring to a state where our universe does not exist. From nothing, not by nothing.